# Trying to get a button to fetch data from database Pyside6

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, pyside6

Building a desktop app using pyside6, trying to get the refresh button to fetch data from a mariadb and insert into a table widget

Class Connectionmaria():
def **init**(self):
print("yes 9")
self.host = "127.0.0.1"
self.user = "root"
self.password = "518Oloko."
self.port = 3306
self.database = "Labpal"
self.con = None
def connect(self):
self.con = mariadb.connect(
host = self.host,
user = self.user,
password = self.password,
port = self.port,
database = self.database
)
def get_data_from_store_db(self):
try:
self.connect()
cursor = self.con.cursor(dictionary=True)
sql = "SELECT * FROM store_log"
cursor.execute(sql)
result = cursor.fetchall()
#print(result)
return result
except Exception as e:
print("get data failed")
finally:
if self.con:
self.con.close

def get_data_from_store_db(self):
try:
self.connect()
cursor = self.con.cursor(dictionary=True)
sql = "SELECT * FROM store_log"
cursor.execute(sql)
result = cursor.fetchall()
#print(result)
return result
except Exception as e:
print("get data failed")
finally:
if self.con:
self.con.close

@Slot(bool)
def on_refreshBtn_clicked(self):
result = Connectionmaria().get_data_from_store_db()
if result:
self.storeTree.setRowCount(len(result))
for row, item in enumerate(result):
column_1_item = QTableWidgetItem(str(item['column 1']))
self.storeTree.setItem(row, 0, column_1_item)
else:
QMessageBox.informaation(self, 'Warning', 'No data gotten from
database')
return

but i keep getting this error when i clicked the refresh button
TypeError: MainWindow.on_refreshBtn_clicked() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a valid [mre], and check its syntax (including indentation) before submitting again.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is not about mariadb or fetching the data.
You made something wrong with connection of a signal from your button to the slot `on_refreshBtn_clicked()`.
You haven't provided this part of your code so it isn't possible to say what you did wrong there.